# How to input range type of value in database?

Tags: html, laravel

I have a drop down box.
There i have to show a price range.
Eg in drop down box
1000 - 10000
20000 - 30000

So how can i insert these kinds of value in database.

```
<Select name="price">
  <option value="????">1000 - 10000</option>
  <option value="????">20000 - 30000</option>
</Select>
```

**what to write in that value (???)**

Comment: You could put the two values separated by some character, no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ultimately a database design question and will depend on your business requirements.

For example, if it were ages:

```
<select name="price">
  <option value="child">0 - 17</option>
  <option value="adult">18 - 99</option>
</select>
```

You would use some kind of classification such as child or adult. In your case, for price, I think something like the following would suffice:

```
<Select name="price">
  <option value="tier1">1000 - 10000</option>
  <option value="tier2">20000 - 30000</option>
</Select>
```

Again, it will depend on business requirements. If you have to perform any maths against the value, it may be better to store as numbers for example.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very unspecific in my point of view. 
In my opinion it depends on how you build the database table and how you need the data on the page itself.
I could imagine that your table could look like this:

```
id | displayValue  | valueFrom | valueUntil

1  | 1000 - 10000  | 1000      | 10000
2  | 20000 - 30000 | 20000     | 30000
```

Then you could enter the ID of the record as value in the option.

```
<Select name="price">
  <option value="1">1000 - 10000</option>
  <option value="2">20000 - 30000</option>
</Select>
```

So in `laravel` it would look like this (if you use `blade`):

```
<Select name="price">
  @foreach($allPrices as $price)
    <option value="{{$price->id}}">{{$price->displayValue}}</option>
  @endforeach
</Select>
```